# Write rule for redirection in IIS7 for codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, iis-7

I am using PHP framework `Codeigniter` and i put an other codeigniter project in it. I write a Redirect URL for 1st one but i am not able to write redirect `URL` for other one, because `ISS7` allows one web.config at time. Now i want to remove the `index.php` from the 2nd one.

The URL for this is

```
https://donate.nfppay.com/external/public_html/
```

The URL for 1st project is

```
https://donate.nfppay.com
```

My code to write rule is:

```
<rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="external/public_html/index.php?/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create a new web.config and place in you sub directory where you have place your second **codeigniter.**
firstly remove your previous rule which you have add.

```
 <remove name="previous rule name"/>
```

and then add this rule

```
 <rule name="Main Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
</rule>
```